# System messages preview does not match live message

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, system-message

I added a system message according to the template Grace Note provided, the source code of the message is the following

```
There will be a short network-wide outage starting on 8/6 19:00 UTC for <a href="http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchange-maintenance-this-saturday/">system maintenance</a>. <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Do not panic.</span>
```

The red "Do not panic" is rendered red in the preview, but not on the actual live system message. It appears without any formatting. I could understand if the formatting for those message would be limited, but the preview should ideally reflect the restrictions that will be imposed on the live system message.

Comment: "Do not panic" does show up in the system message on Gaming.

Comment: @Anna but not in red (and badp modified the template, AFAIK). I'll clarify my question.

Comment: +1 On [scifi.se], “do not panic” is supposed to be written in *[large, friendly letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Don.27t_Panic)*. What's large and friendly about the normal font?

Comment: It doesn't show up at all on [sqa.se]... strange.

Comment: @glowcoder: because you haven't put it there yet...

Comment: @Shog ah, I figured it was a system wide announcement *sheepish look*

Comment: @glowcoder: yeah, it isn't; not sure why not. But it not being is sorta the instigator of this request.

Comment: On the bright side, it made me go and find where in the control panel it is (which isn't in an intuitive place really. Not that I can think of a better place for it.)

Comment: @glow Just don't forget to *remove* the message after the downtime is done. Whenever that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML sanitizer exists [as a JavaScript version](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js) anyway (for the editor preview), so I just hooked it up to the system message preview as well.

Answer (score 2):

We don't allow arbitrary HTML in system messages; it's subject to the same HTML whitelist that every other post on the entire Stack Exchange network is subject to.

[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Comment: From the question it sounds like the HTML sanitizer just isn't hooked up to that preview though, isn't that fixable?

Comment: Then why is it working on some sites?